# Phalcon 1.3.0 using Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query to make LIKE clause

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm trying to make `LIKE '%something%'` with **Phalcon\Mvc\Model\Query** with bound parameters.

Any ideas how to do it?

This didn't work for me:

```
$robots = Robots::query()
->where("type LIKE :type:")
->andWhere("year < 2000")
->bind(array("type" => "mechanical"))
->order("name")
->execute();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. I'm using similar code with only last '%' on the end.

```
$robots = Robots::query()
    ->where("type LIKE :type:")
    ->andWhere("year < 2000")
    // Just add the '%' where you need them:
    ->bind(array("type" => "%mechanical%"))
    ->order("name")
    ->execute();

// OR
$searchTerm = "mechanical";
$robots = Robots::query()
    ->where("type LIKE :type:")
    ->andWhere("year < 2000")
    ->bind(array("type" => "%" . $searchTerm ."%"))
    ->order("name")
    ->execute();
```

I'm not sure if this is intended way of doing this (looks little bit hackish) but it works.